# Need help in logical for practical

Tags: java

i need help where doing this part

"determine how many scores are above or equal to the average and how many scores are below the average."

Can anyone give some idea how to get the output as required

eg: Enter number of quiz scores to process: 5

Score 1: 10

Score 2: 8

Score 3: 9

Score 4: 2

Score 5: 4

Results

=======

Average is 6.6

Number of scores above or equal to the average is 3

Number of scores below the average is 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.print("Enter number of quiz scores to process:");
  int totalScore=scanner.nextInt();

  int[]scoreNum= new int[totalScore];
  
  int i; 
  double total=0.0;
    
  for(i=0;i<totalScore;i++){
  System.out.printf("Score %d:", i+1 );
  scoreNum[i]=scanner.nextInt();
  total += scoreNum[i];
  }
  
  double average=total/totalScore;
  System.out.format("The Average is :%.1f\n",average);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). What is the exact problem you have? You use a simple `if()` and the `<` or `>` operator to see if a value is smaller or bigger another value.

Comment: Looks like you posted only half your code or its  a school assignment. Anyways, coming to the solution, I see you already have average. Now that you have average and entered numbers, just loop over that array `scoreNum` and compare it with `average`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i think the exactly problem i'm having is for to make the user input be a bit of if() as the user input is a part of the loop, where the average declaration and calculation happen after the loop, so i'm facing a problem where i can't make the user input to be a part of the if() statement.

Comment: Your variables are declared well before the for loop, so they're available also after it (at the point where you currently print out the average. You might need another loop to go through the score values again after you've calculate the average.

Comment: @SooKinChun Have a look my answer

Answer (score 3):

Your variables are declared well before the for loop, so they're available also after it (at the point where you currently print out the average. You might need another loop to go through the score values again after you've calculate the average: cc @JuhaLahio

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.print("Enter number of quiz scores to process:");
  int totalScore=scanner.nextInt();

  int[]scoreNum= new int[totalScore];
  
  int i; 
  double total=0.0;
    
  for(i=0;i<totalScore;i++){
  System.out.printf("Score %d:", i+1 );
  scoreNum[i]=scanner.nextInt();
  total += scoreNum[i];
  }
  
  double average=total/totalScore;
  System.out.format("The Average is :%.1f\n",average); 

  int countLesser = 0;
  int countGreater = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < totalScore; i++) {
    if(scoreNum[i] > average) countGreater++;
    else if(scoreNum[i] < average) countLesser++;
  }
  System.out.println("Greater: " + countGreater + " Lesser: " + countGreater);

  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter number of quiz scores to process:");
    int totalScore = scanner.nextInt();
    float[] scores = new float[totalScore];
    float total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < totalScore; i++) {
        System.out.print("Score " + (i + 1) + ": \n");
        scores[i] = scanner.nextFloat();
        total += scores[i];
    }

    float average = total / totalScore;
    int scoresAbove = 0;
    int scoresBelow = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < scores.length; a++) {
        if (scores[a] >= average) {
            scoresAbove++;
        } else {
            scoresBelow++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The average is: " + average + "\n Number of scores above or equal to the average is " + scoresAbove + "\n Number of scores below the average is " + scoresBelow);
```

Comment: thank you, i take your code and try to use the method other comment for me where use array scoreNum and compare it with total / totalScore. and i get these error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Practical3Q1StackoverFlow.main(Practical3Q1StackoverFlow.java:25)

Comment: Maybe you are writing the scores in the same line as the score says, you have to write it under the line that says Score n